# Is there something like 'autotest' for Python unittests?

Tags: python, testing

Basically, growl notifications (or other callbacks) when tests break or pass. **Does anything like this exist?**

If not, it should be pretty easy to write.. Easiest way would be to..

1. run `python-autotest myfile1.py myfile2.py etc.py`

   - Check if files-to-be-monitored have been modified (possibly just if they've been saved).
   - Run any tests in those files.
   - If a test fails, but in the previous run it passed, generate a growl alert. Same with tests that fail then pass.
   - Wait, and repeat steps 2-5.

The problem I can see there is if the tests are in a different file. The simple solution would be to run all the tests after each save.. but with slower tests, this might take longer than the time between saves, and/or could use a lot of CPU power etc..

The best way to do it would be to actually see what bits of code have changed, if function abc() has changed, only run tests that interact with this.. While this would be great, I think it'd be extremely complex to implement?

To summarise:

- Is there anything like the Ruby tool `autotest` (part of the [ZenTest package](http://www.zenspider.com/ZSS/Products/ZenTest/)), but for Python code?
- How do you check which functions have changed between two revisions of a script?
- Is it possible to determine which functions a command will call? (Somewhat like a reverse traceback)

Comment: I don't think it is possible to properly test if you _only_ run tests which directly reference the modified function. You will not test then for how the function interacts with the rest of the code. For example it might pass the test, but fail in practice because its behaviour changed in subtle ways

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I found [autonose](https://github.com/gfxmonk/autonose) to be pretty unreliable but [sniffer](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/sniffer/0.2.3) seems to work very well.

```
$ pip install sniffer
$ cd myproject
```

Then instead of running "nosetests", you run:

```
$ sniffer
```

Or instead of `nosetests --verbose --with-doctest`, you run:

```
$ sniffer -x--verbose -x--with-doctest
```

As described in the [readme](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/sniffer/0.2.3), it's a good idea to install one of the platform-specific filesystem-watching libraries, `pyinotify`, `pywin32` or `MacFSEvents` (all installable via `pip` etc)

Comment: Yes, `sniffer` is the way to go.

Answer (score 16):

[autonose](http://github.com/gfxmonk/autonose/tree/master) created by [gfxmonk](http://gfxmonk.net/):

> Autonose is an autotest-like tool for python, using the excellent nosetest library.
>
> autotest tracks filesystem changes and automatically re-run any changed tests or dependencies whenever a file is added, removed or updated. A file counts as changed if it has iself been modified, or if any file it `import`s has changed.
>
> ...
>
> Autonose currently has a native GUI for OSX and GTK. If neither of those are available to you, you can instead run the console version (with the --console option).

Comment: After fiddling around with `autonose` for a while, I too fell back to `sniffer`. It's not as shiny as `autonose`, but it works as advertised. Even in a virtualenv.

Comment: @exhuma Yep, I found autonose a bit glitchy, and it is no longer actively developed (last commit was 1 year ago as I type this)

Answer (score 3):

I just found this: http://www.metareal.org/p/modipyd/

I'm currently using thumb.py, but as my current project transitions from a small project to a medium sized one, I've been looking for something that can do a bit more thorough dependency analysis, and with a few tweaks, I got modipyd up and running pretty quickly.

Answer (score 3):

[Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) is an excellent tool that monitors for file changes and triggers tasks automatically. It's written in Ruby, but it can be used as a standalone tool for any task like this. There's a [guard-nosetests](https://github.com/medihack/guard-nosetests) plugin to run Python tests via [nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Guard supports cross-platform notifications (Linux, OSX, Windows), including Growl, as well as many other great features. One of my can't-live-without dev tools.

Answer (score 3):

One very useful tool that can make your life easier is [entr](http://entrproject.org/). Written in C, and uses [kqueue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kqueue) or [inotify](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) under the hood.

Following command runs your test suite if any `*.py` file in your project is changed.

```
ls */**.py | entr python -m unittest discover -s test
```

Works for BSD, Mac OS, and Linux. You can get [entr](http://entrproject.org/) from Homebrew.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [nodemon](https://nodemon.io/) for the task, by watching .py files and execute `manage.py test`. The command will be: `nodemon --ext py --exec "python manage.py test"`.

`nodemon` is an npm package however, I assume you have node installed.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe buildbot would be useful http://buildbot.net/trac

Comment: That could work, but it's extremely complicated to setup for what I want. Autotest is started by "cd path/to/my/scripts && autotest", buildbot requires setting up a build slave, setting up a build master (a fairly complicated config)

Answer (score 2):

For your third question, maybe the `trace` module is what you need:

```
>>> def y(a): return a*a
>>> def x(a): return y(a)
>>> import trace
>>> tracer = trace.Trace(countfuncs = 1)
>>> tracer.runfunc(x, 2)
4
>>> res = tracer.results()
>>> res.calledfuncs
{('<stdin>', '<stdin>', 'y'): 1, ('<stdin>', '<stdin>', 'x'): 1}
```

`res.calledfuncs` contains the functions that were called. If you specify `countcallers = 1` when creating the tracer, you can get caller/callee relationships. See the [docs of the `trace` module](http://docs.python.org/lib/trace-api.html) for more information.

You can also try to get the calls via static analysis, but this can be dangerous due to the dynamic nature of Python.

Answer (score 2):

Django's development server has a file change monitor that watches for modifications and automatically reloads itself. You could re-use this code to launch unit tests on file modification.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Nose http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/ has a plugin http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/doc/writing_plugins.html

Found this: http://jeffwinkler.net/2006/04/27/keeping-your-nose-green/

Comment: [nose-watch](https://github.com/lukaszb/nose-watch) is a great plugin. You can autorun your tests like so: `nosetests --with-watch`. Works great

Comment: @toast38coza `nose-watch` doesn't work on Windows(tm)

Answer (score 1):

Check out pytddmon. Here is a video demonstration of how to use it:
http://pytddmon.org/?page_id=33