# Flask: run tests on reload

Tags: unit-testing, flask, karma-runner

I'm working on a flask application and I like the debug feature that reloads the code when a change is detected.  I was working with Karma/Jasmine last week saw it runs the tests when a code change is detected.

Is there a relatively easy way to get this same behavior with Flask so it will run my unit tests when there is a code change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use [Nose](http://flask-testing.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#with-nose) test runner with [nose-watch](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-watch) plugin:

> A Nose plugin that allows to run tests continuously (uses watchdog for
>   listening to filesystem events).

Another option is to use [autonose](https://github.com/gfxmonk/autonose):

> Autonose is an autotest-like tool for python, using the excellent nosetest library.
>
> ...
>
> Re-run tests instantly when you save a file

Also see:

- [Is there something like 'autotest' for Python unittests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108892/is-there-something-like-autotest-for-python-unittests)

Hope that helps.